# How to access individual values from a multi-value returning function?

Tags: go

Go functions can return multiple values:

```
func f() (int, int) {
    return 2, 3
}
```

Is there any way to access individual values from such a multi-value returning function except assignment, i.e. suppose there is

```
func g(i int) {...}
```

is there is simpler way to write the following two lines?

```
_, i = f()
g(i)
```

Comment: I wonder do you yourself have any idea about how this could have been made simpler (on a language syntax level)?

Comment: My favorite would be ``g(f()[1])`` or ``g(f().y)`` if the signature of ``f`` had a named return paramter ``func f() (x int, y int)``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My personal favorite would be `g(f()[1])` but that's not possible either.

The current solution used by the standard library is to write simple helper functions which are dropping the unwanted return values. For example, take a look at the [template](http://golang.org/pkg/template/) package.

A lot of functions there return a `(*Template, os.Error)` tuple, but there is a helper called `template.Must()` which only returns a `*Template` and panics if the error isn't nil.

Alternatively, a general helper function like `func extract(index int, values ...interface{}) interface{}` might do the trick. But since there isn't support for generics yet, I wouldn't write something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Use an anonymous struct instead of multiple return values.

```
func f() (struct{i,j int}) {
    return struct{i, j int}{2, 3}
}

func g(i int) { ... }

func main() {
    g(f().j)
}
```

Of course this only works when you are writing the function. Though you can wrap existing ones with this if you want.

Answer (score -1):

```
g(func(fst,snd int) int { return snd }(f()))
```

or defined snd

```
func snd(x, y int) int {
    return y
}
g(snd(f()))
```

or if function return array

```
func f() ([2]int) {
    return [2]int{2, 3}
}
g(f()[1])
```

Comment: Would you really say that this is simpler? ;) (BTW I believe the compiler will complain about fst being unused if I'm not mistaken.)

Comment: It might not be a simple, no attempt.However, other suitable methods do not think. If all else is an anonymous function and also to define snd.  i try it ,  silence the compiler.

Answer (score -1):

There isn't a simpler way.

A possible solution would look for example like this:

```
g(f().1)
```

There is no syntactic support for a feature like this one in Go.